# Rails 3 update_attributes not working for related model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an `App` which `has_one: live_build`. In the `update` method, I'm running into an issue in Rails 3.2.

Here's the method:

```
if @app.update_attributes(update_params)

  respond_with_json(
    { app: @app.serialize },
    location: nil
  )
else
  respond_with_json(
    { errors: @app.errors },
    status: :unprocessable_entity
  )
end
```

This is a gem that needs to work in both Rails 4 and 3. Everything works in 4, but in 3.2, this doesn't update the `live_build_id`. I verify in the console that

```
@app.update_attributes('live_build_id' => 3)
```

does not work. The only thing that works is `@app.live_build_id = 3` or `@app.live_build = [instance]`.

### Update

The line with `update_params` is actually

```
if @app.update_attributes( use_params(:app_update_params) )
  ..
```

The controller has two additional methods

```
def app_update_params_rails_3
  params[:app].slice(
    :name,
    :require_manual_activation,
    :live_build_id
  )
end

def app_update_params_rails_4
  params.require(:app).permit(
    :name,
    :require_manual_activation,
    :live_build_id
  )
end
```

and inherits from `ApplicationController`, which has this method

```
def use_params(param_method)
  v = Rails::VERSION::MAJOR
  send("#{param_method}_rails_#{v}")
end
```

This is so the gem works with both Rails 3 and 4.

Comment: Yep `@app.valid?` is true

Comment: Only thing I can think of is trying a symbol instead of a string as the hash key

Comment: Can you show us the update_params method?

Comment: Are you using strong parameters?

Comment: `@app.update_attributes( :live_build_id => 4 )` also fails

Comment: It's because it's a protected attribute, I need to whitelist it.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute is protected (rails 3), so I needed to whitelist it in my model:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  if defined?(ProtectedAttributes) || ::ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 4
    attr_accessible :name,
                    :require_manual_activation,
                    :live_build_id
```